# How to Install Chromium 114 in Docker Python 3.10 Image

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, chromium

I'm building a image based on FROM python:3.10
in dockerfile :

```
RUN apt-get install chromium -y
```

get a chromium version 116 and chromium-driver version 114,they are uncampatible using selenium
tried

```
wget -O chromium.deb 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/chromium/chromium_114.0.5735.198-1~deb12u1_amd64.deb'
```

cannot install successful.

Need some help.
Thanks in advance.

My goal is to build a python=3.10 docker image with chromium=114,chromium-driver=114